# ServiceStack ungraceful client disconnect

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

In a ServiceStack app is there any way to determine that the client has ungracefully disconnected? I would like to get a list of users that are online, but

```
var sessionPattern = IdUtils.CreateUrn<IAuthSession>("");
var sessionKeys = Cache.GetKeysStartingWith(sessionPattern).ToList();
var activeSessions = Cache.GetAll<IAuthSession>(sessionKeys).Values;
```

will only get valid sessions, that are valid until they expire or client logouts (which doesn't reflect whether he is onlline or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to Server Events subscriptions, their lifetimes are completely unrelated to User Sessions. A Server Event subscription just represents a long-lived HTTP connection to the Server Events /event-stream which may or may not be from an Authenticated User.

The way to find out [active connected users is to call /event-subscribers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events#active-subscribers).

Inside ServiceStack, all information available on Server Event subscriptions is [accessible through the IServerEvents](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events#active-subscribers) dependency, e.g. To find out all active subscriptions for a user you can call GetSubscriptionInfosByUserId()

Comment: `ServerEvents.GetAllSubscriptionsDetails();` still cant get dead subscriptions (of clients that are disconnected ungracefully)

Comment: @HardLuck if the subscription is determined to be disconnected it gets automatically removed.

Comment: yes but i was looking for a way to refresh subscriptions list on the server for the case when client didn't notify the server about his disconnection

Comment: @HardLuck This is automatically handled by the heartbeats which tell ServerEvents whether a connection is no longer alive which it will automatically dispose. If you want to force the unregistration of a subscription you can call `IServerEvents.UnRegister()`.